# Construct time in local, then convert to another timezone

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I am using moment-timezone. I am in Los Angeles. It is 9pm here on April 21, I construct that like this:

```
const ca = moment('4/21/2020 9pm', 'M/D/YYYY ha');
```

Doing `ca.valueOf()` gives `1587528000000`.

However when I do `ca.clone().tz('America/New_York').valueOf()` it still gives same. I am expecting it should be `1587538800000`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`valueOf` is unix timestamp in milliseconds. You can change Timezone, but this still represents the same *single precise instant* in time, even if it is shown in a different way (3 + 1 is the same as 2 + 2 even if they're written in differents way)

Comment: How can I make moment adjust the unix timestamp so that it adds 3 hours based on time diff between new york and los angeles?